# Ubuntu 14.04.3 - Wifi Intel 8260 doesn't work

Tags: networking, drivers

I recently purchased a laptop Mountain (reseller of Clevo), and while installing Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.3 (in dual boot with Windows), I noticed that the WiFi module doesn't work. I think to try upgrading system, but without WiFi I can't, and actually I don't have the way to connect by Ethernet.

I tried to search driver for Ubuntu, but I didn't found it.

Can I do something to make WiFi work?

Thank you

Comment: You probably *can't* get it to work in 14.04. I suggest you try the live DVD for 15.10.

Comment: The Wifi module on my new notebook required me to update to Kernel 4.X Check your kernel version with: uname -a

Comment: I run that command, and the system give me this: Linux RASTUNTU 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.  So I think I will need to update to kernel 4.X, right?

Comment: Ok, I will try it too. If I can't make it work on 14.04, I will need to install 15.10. I prefer LTS version, but... Thank you

Comment: That might solve your problem, it did for my Intel dual-band wifi module at least. Try running:

Comment: `sudo apt-cache search linux-image`

and

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.2.0-23-generic`

(or replace with any other 4.x kernel version you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to connect to the internet physically or through a usb nic, to update ubuntu. The update will fix your issue!

```
    sudo apt-get update 
    sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after a restart you should be up and running!
Good Luck, Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Maybe tomorrow I will can go to a friend house to connect it by Ethernet. I will update this thread with the result. Thanks for answering ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I tried to update & upgrade, but it dont worked.

So, before trying with Ubuntu 15.10, I tried L_W advice and I updated to kernel 4.3.0.X. And now it works!!

So thanks for the help, anyone with this problem or a problem with a new laptop, try updating the kernel.